# Facebook create a browser session starting from access_token

Tags: python, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After my app receives the access token from facebook through OAuth2 python API (facepy) in my backend, I need to open a webview ios for showing the fb request dialog (something like https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=394119460629357&message=ComeToPlayWithPrintUP&redirect_uri=http://www.photosi.com)

I want to create an authenticated web view instance using the access token that I have so that the user doesn't have to log in again.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a feature of the API - for the webview to have access to a user's Facebook data they must be logged into Facebook's website and have the session/login cookies available to that webview; I don't think this is possible with Safari

Comment: Is there any chance to start an FB authenticated web session inside a webview if I've already got an access token in a previous oauth2 flow outside this webview?

Comment: No, there is no way to have a webview be logged into Facebook unless the user logged into Facebook in the webview itself or into the browser which provides the rendering for that webview (assuming cookies are passed to the webview, which they are not usually)